# The relationship between degree of vertex and size of dominating set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I was wondering is there any relationship between degree of vertex and size of dominating set. For example, if I know the number of vertices is $n$, and I could know each vertex in the graph has degree $\ge n^k \,(k< 1)$, is it possible to bound the size of dominating set, i.e $O(n^k)$? Could anyone point me out any materials/papers/books related to this problem?

Comment: cross-posted [from cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/33721/6973) without mentioning that on either site ​ ​

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was simultaneously cross-posted on another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.